# low-cost transmitter and receiver, no MCU involved hopefully

Tags: rf, basic

a newbie on electronics here.

I would like to create a simple RF kit. on transmitter side, only 1 button. on receiver side, if a valid code is received, a relay activates to provide 12VDC to a load.

i would like the transmitter to send out a unique code so that it doesn't activate another receiver kit.

any suggestion on how to send out a unique code without MCU? i would like the solution to be low cost, off the shelf, and can fit inside a typical car key fob case.

thanks in advance!

Comment: I think Holtek used to make a code transmitter and receiver? Gives you somewhere to look.

Answer (score 0):

You can find finished units for about $20 on the big electrical part supplier sites.  Search for "RF remote module".  They usually have a logic level output that's active high or low, so you'll probably need a transistor to drive the relay, but depending on the load you might be able to get away with using a bigger transistor that can power your load directly.

Answer (score 0):

A garage door opener chipset :D they are making them for something like 40 years now…
in one common implementation they handle 4 bits so you send 4 buttons and receive 4 relays or 2 bistable relays.

The old ones only did the bitstream handling: the RF section is separate (they where also used for infrared, ultrasound and so on). Most commonly they are used in CW on some ISM band.

I don't actually have used them but these days the PT2262/PT2272 pair seems to be quite popular, but I'm sure there are many others around